# jw player it is not working if I use a config file

Tags: jwplayer, configuration-files

If I use:

```
player.swf?config=http://example.com/embed/video.php?id=weILNyHEqmI
```

with the code:

```
<config>
  <link>http://example.com/</link>
  <file>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=weILNyHEqmI</file>
  <image>http://example.com/path-to-image.png</image>
  <repeat>true</repeat>
  <autostart>false</autostart>
</config>
```

it shows :

> Video not found:
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=weILNyHEqmI

What is the problem? What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the provider to youtube?

```
provider=youtube
```

And are you reference the yt.swf? You need to host it for youtube video, if you look in Firebug where your player you should see a call to it.

Comment: yes, that was the problem. and in firefox it showed me that yt.swf had a 404 response; this file should be in the same folder with player.swf.